# Flutter - My screen is not refreshing after notifying changes

Tags: flutter

I'm encountering a minor issue with updating my screen upon logging out of the account in my app.

I understand that this question has been asked before, but I've already tried all the recommended solutions provided in other inquiries. I've used setState to refresh the screen and I've also created a Notifier using ChangeNotifier, which works fine when logging in but not when logging out.

Currently, I've implemented a Bottom Navigation Bar with a navigation router using the Stateful Shell Branch. Now, I want to refresh two screens to display different views for logged-in and logged-out users. While I'm able to refresh upon login, the notifier doesn't seem to work for logging out, and the changes aren't reflected in the view.

This is the principal view of my widget:
I want to change between the logged and guest view, and in every change of preferencesProvider I invoke notifyListeners().

```
class SettingsView extends ConsumerWidget {
  const SettingsView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    UserModel? user = ref.watch(preferencesProvider).user;
    bool logged = (user != null);

    return SafeArea(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: UserCard(
              user: user,
            ),
          ),
          (logged)
              ? LoggedSettingsItems(user: user)
              : const GuestSettingsItems(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code in the logged-in view:
When I invoke the **cerrarSesion** method, I want to refresh the entire screen. I've attempted to use setState and the ChangeNotifier methods for this purpose. Additionally, I've tried manipulating Riverpod methods, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

```
class LoggedSettingsItems extends ConsumerWidget {
  final UserModel? user;
  const LoggedSettingsItems({super.key, this.user});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ref) {
    List<String> items;
    List<IconData> icons;
    List<Function> functions;

    items = ['Modificar Cuenta', 'Ajustes', 'Cerrar Sesión'];
    icons = [LineIcons.userEdit, LineIcons.cog, LineIcons.alternateSignOut];
    functions = [modificarCuenta, ajustesAplicacion, cerrarSesion];

    return SliverFixedExtentList(
      itemExtent: 50,
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            leading: Icon(icons[index]),
            title: Text(items[index]),
            onTap: () => functions[index](ref, context),
          );
        },
        childCount: items.length,
      ),
    );
  }

  void modificarCuenta(WidgetRef ref, BuildContext context) {}
  void ajustesAplicacion(WidgetRef ref, BuildContext context) {}
  void cerrarSesion(WidgetRef ref, BuildContext context) async {
    final bool isGoogleSigned =
        await ref.read(userDatasourceProvider).isGoogleSigned();
    ref.watch(userSignInProvider.notifier).signOut(isGoogleSigned);
    ref.read(preferencesProvider.notifier).clearUserData();
    CustomAlertDialog.showAlertDialog(
        context, 'Cerrar Sesión', '¿Seguro desea cerrar sesión?', () {
      ref.read(preferencesProvider.notifier).clearUserData();
    }, null);
  }
}
```

This is the code inside my preferences provider:

```
final preferencesProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<PreferencesNotifier, PreferencesState>(
        (ref) => PreferencesNotifier());

class PreferencesState extends ChangeNotifier {
  final UserModel? user;

  final bool allowNotification;

  PreferencesState({this.user, this.allowNotification = true});

  PreferencesState copyWith({UserModel? user, bool? allowNotification}) {
    return PreferencesState(
        user: user ?? this.user,
        allowNotification: allowNotification ?? this.allowNotification);
  }

  void notify() => notifyListeners();
}

class PreferencesNotifier extends StateNotifier<PreferencesState> {
  final Preferences prefs = Preferences();
  PreferencesNotifier() : super(PreferencesState());

  void setUserData(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    prefs.setUserData(json);
    state = state.copyWith(user: UserModel.fromJson(json));
    state.notify();
  }

  void clearUserData() async {
    prefs.clearUserData();
    state = state.copyWith(user: null);
    state.notify();
  }

  void setAllowNotifications(bool value) {
    prefs.setAllowNotifications(value);
    state = state.copyWith(allowNotification: value);
    state.notify();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for preferences provider?

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I updated the post with the code for preferences provider